# Why is my code not completing the Sound::release() call?

Tags: c++, mp3, fmod

I am creating a simple MP3 player and using the FMOD Core API for managing the audio. I have written a simple program to test the `play()` function.
I have two functions `freeSound()` and `freeSystem()` to free the `sound` and the `system` handle respectively. Both are called through the function `cleanUp()` in the destructor.

I have used `gdb` to figure out that for some reason, my program gets stuck in the `Sound::release()` call in `freeSound()` when the destructor is called.

This problem occurs only when `freeSystem()` is called before `freeSound()`. Simply calling the latter first fixes this issue.

I have shared as little code as I thought was possible to show this problem. If more/less is required I will add/remove.

The main() function:

```cpp
int main()
{
    musicPlayer p{"music.mp3"};
    std::cout << "load success\n";
    p.play();
    std::cout << "press enter to quit\n";
    std::cin.get();
}
```

The class declaration (includes only relevant bits):

```cpp
class musicPlayer
{
private:
    FMOD::System *m_system = nullptr;
    FMOD::Sound *m_sound = nullptr;

    /*Some more functions*/

    void cleanUp();
    void freeSystem();
    void freeSound();

public:
    ~musicPlayer();

    /*Some more functions*/
};
```

Destructor:

```cpp
musicPlayer::~musicPlayer()
{
    cleanUp();
    m_channel = nullptr;
}
```

cleanUp():

```cpp
void musicPlayer::cleanUp()
{
    freeSystem();
    freeSound();
}
```

freeSound() and freeSystem():

```cpp
void musicPlayer::freeSystem()
{
    if(m_system == nullptr)
        return;

    FMOD_RESULT result = m_system -> release();
    if(result != FMOD_OK){
        std::cerr << "freeSystem() Error: " << FMOD_ErrorString(result) << "\n";
        return;
    }
    else 
        m_system = nullptr;
}

void musicPlayer::freeSound()
{
    if(m_sound == nullptr)
        return;

    FMOD_RESULT result = m_sound -> release();
    if(result != FMOD_OK){
        std::cerr << "freeSound() Error: " << FMOD_ErrorString(result) << "\n";
        return;
    }
    else
        m_sound = nullptr;
}
```

I expect the audio to stop playing and the program to immediately quit when enter is pressed.

Instead, on pressing enter, the audio stops and the program does not quit.

**UPDATE:**

Earlier, I wrote:

> Blockquote
>   I have written little test programs where I have called `System::release()` before `Sound::release()`. Such programs do not exhibit this issue.

I was wrong. The issue can be reproduced by playing a sound, calling `cin.get()` and then freeing the resources in the order wrong order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FMOD reference [FMOD System::close](https://fmod.com/resources/documentation-api?version=2.0&page=core-api-system.html#system_close) should explain the behaviour:

"Closing renders objects created with this System invalid. Make sure any Sound, ChannelGroup, Geometry and DSP objects are released before calling this.".

System::close is called by [System::release](https://fmod.com/resources/documentation-api?version=2.0&page=core-api-system.html#system_release) so when releasing the system before the components you stumble into problems. As you have found out yourself simply free everything before you release the system.

Comment: Thanks ! It turns out I can reproduce the problem in a test program by playing the sound, calling `cin.get()` and releasing resources in the wrong order.